# Using OOP/Class Module called "FastMode" to toggle Application object properties in Excel

Tags: object-oriented, vba, classes

I'm programming a tool in Excel which reads two exported .csv files, performs some calculations based on `Dates` and `Strings` and populates a dashboard to be copied into a Google Sheet daily report.

Although the exported data would be no more than 150 rows (across two worksheets), I wrote a small routine to toggle "`FastMode`".

`FastMode` is for updating the following `Application` object properties;

- `ScreenUpdating`
- `Calculation`
- `DisplayAlerts`

As the need for the tool was very sudden (as the only option was manually count - I don't like tedious counting) the initial code was very poorly written and the `FastMode` toggle was just a block of code in the main `Sub` with *procedure level* declarations used to capture the 'current' values for these properties and a *public level* boolean for `IsFastMode` to evaluate if `FastMode` was toggled **on** or **off**.

---

I'm now revising the code, using the opportunity to practise and learn VBA programming skills on a 'real life' problem.

I've revised the `FastMode` part of the code a few times now, first to it's own `Public Sub ToggleFastMode` in the main routine Module with *arguments* to allow passing the *procedure level* variables for the 'current' values.

I've now replaced the `Public IsFastMode` boolean with a Class Module property `Status` which has also been updated as the *DefaultMember* and moved the <s>`ToggleFastMode`</s> `Toggle` sub into the new Class Module.

### FastMode *Class Module*

```
'@Folder("DailyJobsUpdated")
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit

Private Type ToggleFastMode
    NewStatus As Boolean
End Type
Private This As ToggleFastMode

'@DefaultMember
Public Property Get Status() As Boolean
    Status = This.NewStatus
End Property

Public Property Let Status(ByVal NewValue As Boolean)
    This.NewStatus = NewValue
End Property

Public Sub Toggle(ByVal ScreenUpdate As Boolean, ByVal Calculate As Long, ByVal DisplayAlert As Boolean)
    With Application
        If FastMode Then
            .ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdate
            .Calculation = Calculate
            .DisplayAlerts = DisplayAlert
            FastMode = False
        ElseIf Not FastMode Then
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            .DisplayAlerts = False
            FastMode = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This would be called from within the main routine like so:

```
...
    Dim ScreenUpdateBool As Boolean
    Dim CalculationMethodConst As Long
    Dim DisplayAlertBool As Boolean
    
    With Application
        ScreenUpdateBool = .ScreenUpdating
        CalculationMethodConst = .Calculation
        DisplayAlertBool = .DisplayAlerts
    End With
    
    On Error GoTo Safety
    
    If Not FastMode Then FastMode.Toggle ScreenUpdateBool, CalculationMethodConst, DisplayAlertBool
...
```

---

As I'm still learning and wrapping my head around using Class Modules in my code, I'm specifically interested in;

- Is the implementation of the `Toggle` sub into the Class Module the appropriate location to house this routine?
- Is setting the `Status` property as the  default member (using *RubberDuck*) a "*bad*" idea? (I'm not too worried about every little possibility of issues, just if there are common problems run into by setting default members in Class Modules).
- Have I broken any general rules with the way I've written this Class Module?
- Will it be *more correct* to set additional properties in the Class to be used in place of the *Procedure level* variables that are passed to the `Toggle` sub?

Any other feedback is welcomed.

Comment: Sees `'@Folder()`. Smiles at another RubberDuck user!

Comment: I would store the previous values in private properties. Then when it's turned off you restore the previous values, instead of hard coded values. You also need some error handling to avoid leaving it in an undesirable state.

Comment: Well done on practising writing classes.  Unfortunately, the use of a class in this particular case is completely the wrong solution.

Comment: I've left an explanation on this topic a while ago [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/255006/227582) and explained why it's correct to store/restore the state without making any assumptions. Just the first section is of interest to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### About "Fast" Code

I take [mild] issue with "fast mode" and similar "optimize speed" wordings, because code that needs these switches toggled is very often code that is simply inefficient, and turning off calculations and screen repaints makes the macro complete faster, *without making it any more efficient*. Minimizing worksheet accesses (both reading and writing) normally makes the code run much faster, and when a macro involves a single worksheet read and a single worksheet write operation, toggling calculations and repaints off isn't going to change anything.

That said, there *are* times when such toggling is needed and/or beneficial. I'd go with `HostApplicationState` or something similarly neutral as far as alluding to any performance gains goes - simply because when the code is efficient in the first place, then the effect of these toggles is very marginal.

---

#### Naming

`FastMode` aside, `NewStatus` is confusing and has no reason to *not* be just `Status`: one of the advantages of using a `Private Type` for the backing field of properties, is that you get to name each field *exactly* as per the property member it's backing. Naming it differently defeats that purpose and makes `Property` members more confusing than necessary.

The `NewValue` parameter name is appropriate for a `Property Let` (or `Set`) value parameter identifier name; `Value` or `RHS` (for *right-hand-side*) would also be appropriate.

---

#### State Corruption

The predeclared instance is stateful, which comes with a number of implications: the state is effectively global, and `FastMode.Toggle` is working off that global state... but the `Status` property being writable is making it very easy to misuse the class and essentially corrupt the state, which would be causing bugs downstream.

Because the `Toggle` method assumes an *enabled* initial state, nesting instances would also corrupt the state.

```
Dim Test1 As FastMode '<~ this declaration is always legal
Set Test1 = New FastMode '<~ local instance has its own Status

FastMode.Toggle True, True, True '<~ Boolean arguments are bad for readability
Debug.Print FastMode '<~ default instance Status is True
Debug.Print Test1 '<~ local instance Status is still False
Test1 = True '<~ local instance write to Status is legal
FastMode = False '<~ manual toggle doesn't actually toggle the Application state
```

The `Boolean` parameters are confusing and should be avoided altogether: it's hard to tell whether the `Toggle` method is expecting `True` or `False`: the method isn't actually "toggling" the state so "true" isn't saying "yeah I want to toggle this one" but rather "make it true/false as I say", which is leaking the encapsulated global state into the abstraction.

So the first thing I would change would be to make `Status` read-only by outright deleting the `Property Let` member. The property being the class' default member isn't ideal, *because it is parameterless*. With the default/predeclared instance, that makes the meaning of a `FastMode` token highly context-dependent. Parameterless default members are illegal in VB.NET where the `Set` keyword is deprecated. Now, the `Status` property is a `Boolean` data type, so resolving the default member call isn't too hard: the member implicitly invoked is defined in the `FastMode` class. When a class' default member returns another object type (which could have its own default member), resolving default member calls becomes a recursive operation, and we're looking at *code that says one thing and does another*.

This could be fixed in two ways:

1. Query `This.FastMode` in the `Toggle` method, making it work off the state *of the current instance*, i.e. each instance of the class gets its own state.
2. Return `FastMode.Status` rather than `This.Status` in the `Property Get Status` member; conditionally return `This.Status` when `Me Is FastMode`: only the default instance actually holds any state.

Going with 2 is simpler, but then it makes instances of the `FastMode` class rather deceptive, since the state is actually held in the default instance: because no instance is holding any state, it becomes very difficult to justify using a class over a standard module here, because OOP and global state don't really work well together.

---

#### Alternative

I would suggest a simpler API involving a `With` block to eliminate the *temporal coupling* that forces the client code to invoke the `Toggle` method - the calling code might look like this:

```
With FastMode.Toggle
   '...do stuff...
End With
```

Or like this:

```
With FastMode.Toggle(AppState_Calculation Or AppState_ScreenUpdating)
   '...do stuff...
End With
```

Side note: this `Or` operator is bitwise-OR; a `+` operator could be used instead, but using `Or` in a bitwise context emphasizes the bitwise nature of the enum values.

The class' `Initialize` handler would be responsible for encapsulating the initial application state at instance level, and the `Terminate` handler would be responsible for restoring it... *except* for the default instance.

Because each instance is storing the application state *as it is at the moment of initialization*, instances can be safely nested; when an instance goes out of scope, application state gets restored to what it was when *that instance* was created. Guarding the mechanism against a stateful default instance seems wise here.

The `Toggle` method becomes essentially a *factory method* that toggles the application state, optionally only affecting a subset. The result of this, is a more robust API that makes both `With New FastMode` and `With FastMode.Toggle` behave identically. Since a *factory method* is involved, we want to supply and implement an explicit interface that I'll call `IAppState` here.

That `IAppState` interface might look like this - note that all we need of this interface is for it to provide a way to access an instance's encapsulated initial state, so that's where we'll want to have a property per setting:

```
'@ModuleDescription "An object that encapsulates initial application state."
'@Interface
Option Explicit

Public Property Get InitialCalculation() As XlCalculation
End Property

Public Property Get InitialScreenUpdating() As Boolean
End Property

Public Property Get InitialDisplayAlerts() As Boolean
End Property
```

Next we'd have a `HostApplicationState` class that implements this interface:

```
'@ModuleDescription "An object that toggles global application state as needed."
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit
Implements IAppState

Public Enum AppStateEnum
    AppState_None = 0

    'underlying values must be powers of 2:
    AppState_Calculation = 1
    AppState_ScreenUpdating = 2
    AppState_DisplayAlerts = 4

    'convenience member to include all properties:
    AppState_All = AppState_Calculation Or _
                   AppState_ScreenUpdating Or _
                   AppState_DisplayAlerts
End Enum

Private Type TState
    AppProperties As AppStateEnum
    InitialCalculation As XlCalculation
    InitialScreenUpdating As Boolean
    InitialDisplayAlerts As Boolean
End Type

Private This As TState

'@Description "Disables the specified global application properties; properties will toggle back on when object goes out of scope."
Public Function Toggle(Optional ByVal AppProperties As AppStateEnum = AppState_All) As IAppState
    Dim Result As HostApplicationState
    Set Result = New HostApplicationState '<~ Initialize handler runs here
    Result.AppProperties = AppProperties

    If HasFlag(AppProperties, AppStateEnum.AppState_Calculation) Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End If

    If HasFlag(AppProperties, AppStateEnum.AppState_ScreenUpdating) Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    End If

    If HasFlag(AppProperties, AppStateEnum.AppState_DisplayAlerts) Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End If

    Set Toggle = Result
End Function

'@Description "Gets or sets the properties managed by this instance."
Public Property Get AppProperties() As AppStateEnum
    AppProperties = This.AppProperties
End Property

Public Property Let AppProperties(ByVal Values As AppStateEnum)
    This.AppProperties = Values
End Property

'@Description "A helper function performing bitwise logic for flag enums."
Private Function HasFlag(ByVal value As Long, ByVal flag As Long) As Boolean
    HasFlag = (value And flag) = flag
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    'Default instance is stateless:
    If Me Is HostApplicationState Then Exit Sub
    'affect all managed properties by default (use .Toggle to narrow it down):
    This.AppProperties = AppStateEnum.AppState_All

    This.InitialCalculation = Application.Calculation
    This.InitialScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
    This.InitialDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    'Default instance is stateless:
    If Me Is HostApplicationState Then Exit Sub
    'only restore the properties that were toggled...
    If HasFlag(This.AppProperties, AppStateEnum.AppState_Calculation) Then
        Application.Calculation = This.InitialCalculation
    End If
    If HasFlag(This.AppProperties, AppStateEnum.AppState_ScreenUpdating) Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = This.InitialScreenUpdating
    End If
    If HasFlag(This.AppProperties, AppStateEnum.AppState_DisplayAlerts) Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = This.InitialDisplayAlerts
    End If
End Sub

Private Property Get IAppState_InitialCalculation() As XlCalculation
    IAppState_InitialCalculation = This.InitialCalculation
End Property

Private Property Get IAppState_InitialScreenUpdating() As Boolean
    IAppState_InitialScreenUpdating = This.InitialScreenUpdating
End Property

Private Property Get IAppState_InitialDisplayAlerts() As Boolean
    IAppState_InitialDisplayAlerts = This.InitialDisplayAlerts
End Property
```

Implemented like this, state is no longer global, and each instance encapsulates its own `Initial[ApplicationProperty]` values to use for restoring the `Application` state to exactly what it was before the object came into existence.

Now the API is looking like this:

```
With HostApplicationState.Toggle '<~ all managed properties get disabled
    'note: the only available members are the .Initial[ApplicationProperty] getters
    '...do stuff...
End With '<~ all managed properties get toggled back on
```

That is functionally equivalent to this - note the `Toggle` member call; including it in the `Initialize` handler would remove the need to have it in the client code here, but then it would also make it needlessly invoked twice when using the preferred factory method, and we don't want a side-effecting `Initialize` handler anyway so if client code decides to `New` up the class, `Toggle` needs to be explicitly invoked:

```
With New HostApplicationState
    .Toggle '<~ all managed properties get disabled
    'note: .Toggle and .AppProperties members are accessible, but not the .Initial[ApplicationProperty] getters.
    '...do stuff...
End With '<~ all managed properties get toggled back on
```

While it "works", it isn't leveraging the class' default instance, which makes the `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute useless. Still, it would probably work fine without breaking anything. Obviously it can be abused by changing the `AppProperties` value before the object goes out of scope, but then such *wrong code* would *look wrong*, and that's perfect (and guard clauses can actively prevent such misuse by throwing an error in the `Property Let` scope).

And if `do stuff` involves invoking a procedure that specifically needs alerts turned off, then that macro can do this:

```
With HostApplicationState.Toggle(AppState_DisplayAlerts)
    'note: Application.DisplayAlerts state before the With block is irrelevant
    '...do stuff
End With
```

And when *that* instance goes out of scope (i.e. when the `With` block is exited - note that this covers jumping out of the `With` block on error); if that instance is nested and the outer instance has already toggled `DisplayAlerts`, then this inner instance is redundant because its `InitialDisplayAlerts` is going to be `False` - by encapsulating the initial state, it's making fewer assumptions.

Perhaps `Manage` would be a better name than `Toggle` here:

```
With HostApplicationState.Manage(AppState_Calculation Or AppState_ScreenUpdating)
    '...do stuff...
    With HostApplicationState.Manage(AppState_DisplayAlerts)
        '...do more stuff... (calc and repaints are still disabled)
    End With '<~ alerts are back on here
    '...do stuff...
End With '<~ calc and repaints are re-enabled here (assuming "enabled" initial state)
```

Of course the biggest caveat with such a class with a side-effecting `Terminate` handler is that you want to limit its lifetime as much as possible (`With` blocks are *perfect* for this!), so the ultimate misuse of that class would be to have a module-scope variable of that type.

Lastly, note that there is no need for a `Boolean` value to track whether state is enabled or not: that "active" state is made explicit by the caller using a `With` block to *with*old the object instance. In other words if the object is alive, it is also active: the caller is in charge of the object's lifetime, and therefore of exactly when the application state gets toggled off and/or back on.

Comment: Side note: the `IAppState` interface isn't really needed [anymore; it *was* at some point in the refactoring process], but it does help clarifying the API by exposing the initial state to the caller and hiding members that shouldn't be invoked after the object is created and returned.

Comment: Re-reading again, the manual `.Toggle` call when the class is explicitly `New`'d up is problematic, because the state is getting encapsulated in an instance that promptly gets discarded... so more work is needed to actually make it work nicely that way - anyway the `With` block and factory method approach is preferred, since it makes the instance's lifetime explicit.

Comment: I learned a lot - as always. I hadn't thought of *fast code* and the readability (or lack thereof) of `Booleans` in the perspective you put them. The **State Corruption** and your alternative are extremely valuable to me - I'll continue to research on these (still not quite there!). I can't thank you enough for the valuable review (much like all the previous)!